# Reading/Parsing config file in VS2010 C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I am working on VS2010 C++/ clr project. I need to initialize some variables which are part of C++ code ( just for clarification , not of C++/CLI code ). Temporarily I have created config.txt file and reading values from that file. It's working file.

But I want some safer/well-tested library for reading/parsing config files.Can anyone point me to right direction in this.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) in our project. PropertyTree can read different kinds of config files, e.g. ini, xml or json.

This [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html) may help for a start.

Comment: Yes I have tried using that but getting a linker error "error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013119F) : A TypeRef exists which should, but does not, have a corresponding TypeDef" For that I tried using #pragma managed(push, off)
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>
#pragma managed(pop)          after which I was able to compile but my code crashed.